# How do I save a value in global in Jest during test setup?

Tags: jestjs

I have a global setup in Jest.

```json
"jest": {
    "globalSetup": "./setup.js"
  }
```

Within the setup, I have an async function which writes a session key to global

```js
const axios = require('axios');

async function getSessionKey() {
    const response = await axios.post("http://apiUrl", {
        username: "K",
        password: "passw0rd"
    });
    sessionKey = response.data.sessionKey;
    global.sessionKey = sessionKey;
}

module.exports = getSessionKey;
```

Whatever session key I am saving in global is not available in the test file. global.sessionKey is undefined in the below test.

```js
test("create session", () => {
    expect(global.sessionKey).toBeTruthy();
});
```

I want some way to set the sessionKey in a global object from setup file. The session key should be available before I run any of my tests.

Comment: Possibly a bug with Jest - https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/5424. For now, I replaced Jest with Mocha in my project and everything is good!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`globalSetup`/`globalTeardown` can't be used to inject context/global variables to sandboxed test suites/files. Use [`setupFiles`](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#setupfiles-array)/[`setupFilesAfterEnv`](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#setupfilesafterenv-array) instead.

Other way you can customize the test runtime through `testEnvironment`, more details see here: [Async setup of environment with Jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48508847/async-setup-of-environment-with-jest/48511617?noredirect=1#comment84028377_48511617)

Comment: how should I use the `setupFiles`?
it says in the docs that I can add this as a field in package.json in jest subfields, but it only says it should be an array and that the default value is `[ ]`.
so what should I do if I want to add for instance, a `jest.setTimeout(10000);` config there?

Answer (score 3):

I spend a lot of time figuring this out right. The only fully working solution was using testenvironments. This supports async functions as well as globals properly. Each test suite uses a separate instance of the testenvironment.

```js
const NodeEnvironment = require('jest-environment-node');

class TestEnvironment extends NodeEnvironment {
  constructor(config) {
    super(config);
  }

  async setup() {
    await super.setup();
    this.global.db = await asyncCode();
  }

  async teardown() {
    this.global.db = null;
    await asyncCode2();
    await super.teardown();
  }

  runScript(script) {
    return super.runScript(script);
  }
}

module.exports = TestEnvironment;
```

I added a reference to this file in the Jest Config: `"testEnvironment": "./testEnvironment"` for the file `testEnvironment.js`

I'm not sure though why there are so many different config options like setupFiles, globals, testEnvironment, ...

Comment: This runs per test suite and can't share memory between instances. It's basically like beforeAll and afterAll hooks.

Answer (score 3):

Setting an env variable like `process.env.SESSION_KEY = sessionKey` from `globalSetup` seems to work for me in subsequent tests.

I can access the value properly from any test. Not sure if this is a bug or a feature.

Comment: It’s between a bug and a feature. I use it since it’s pretty much the only meaningful way to communicate between Jest setup and tests.

There’s supposed to be a proper feature for passing serializable data from setup to tests, and once that is out, the env way may be closed.